# QR (write2DBarcode) Code on TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, printing, qr-code, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF with two different QR code in the same line, but I'm getting the second QR code in a different size, Please check below code and picture.

```
        $pdf->write2DBarcode('http://xxxx.xxx.php?sc='.$linha_id_to_print->xxx, 'QRCODE,Q', 7,62,15,15, $style, 'N');
        $pdf->write2DBarcode('http://xxxx.xxx.php?sc='.$linha_id_to_print->xxx, 'QRCODE,Q', 32,62,15,15, $style, 'N');

        $pdf->SetFont('arial','',5);
        $pdf->MultiCell(19, 2, 'FIRST QR', 1, 'C',false, 0, 5, 78, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
        $pdf->MultiCell(19, 2, 'SECOND QR', 1, 'C',false, 0, 30, 78, true, 0, false, true, 0, 'T', false);
```

[image: QR Codes]

How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the second qrcode is not extrapolating the page margin.

You can modify the page margins using the methods below:

```
    $pdf->SetMargins(0,0, 0);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
```